# Why this js code can loop?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var c=0
var t
function timedCount()
{
document.getElementById('txt').value=c
c=c+1
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000)
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="begin to count！" onClick="timedCount()">
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

the function timedCount has no loop in it, but when I click the button, the value of id='txt' will constantly increase?

Comment: The function is recursive (kind of): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion .

Comment: "Why this js code can loop?" — um, because JavaScript is Turing-complete…?

Comment: Because of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) - a preferred way of calling this is `setTimeout(timedCount,1000)` without the quotes and brackets. Also add semicolons after each statement in case you would ever want to minify this

Comment: you see this line `setTimeout("timedCount()",1000)`, you are setting a timer to call the event in 1000ms everytime you execute it. thus gets called again and again with that interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `setTimeOut` your `timedCount()` function executes after each and every `1000ms` as you set. If you want to stop the loop use clearTimeout(); function.

like:

```
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000)
clearTimeout(t); //it clears the time out function iteration.
```

**update**

You can call `setTimeOut` function without quotes:

```
function timedCount() {
    document.getElementById("txt").value = c;
    c++;
    t = setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);
}
```

or using an anonymous function:

```
t = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("txt").value = c;
    c++;
}, 1000);
```

Reference:

- [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)
- [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

This occurs due to the principles of [recursion](http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/understanding-recursion-in-functional-javascript-programming/).

This code will never terminate because before the method has a chance to exit, the method is called again.

```
function method()
{
  method();
}
```

This is very similar to code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

your timedCount function calls after every one second so your variable is going to increase.. Settimeout work as timer control in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The js timeout method call a function once after a specified amount of time, as you are calling the same function after the specified amount of time it calls itself again which results in another call to the timeout function repeating the process as a loop or recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
function timedCount()
{
     document.getElementById('txt').value=c
     c=c+1
     t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000)
 }
```

here timedCount() every time called when inside these function. so it's make infinite loop.